# Android Activity UI Performance (AsyncTask while-loop)

Tags: android, multithreading, while-loop, android-asynctask

How can I make this more efficient, at the moment it hangs the activity, giving the following information in logcat every time the while-loop completes I assume:

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its
main thread.
```

Basically on a while-loop it reads a string variable, modifies and splits the string into parts which are then multiplied then divided, these final values are picked up by an interface which changes the custom UI element in the activity.

This seems too heavy on the main UI thread, I was under the impression that handler.post alleviates some of this by adding to the message queue however there are skipped frames.

I've tried to convert this code into an AsyncTask however I don't understand how this code can be converted to work in AsyncTask.

---

**EDIT:** AsyncTask custom class replacing old Thread while-loop.

(Old code for reference: http://pastebin.com/Dek6uQTE)

I'm still unsure how this fits in with AsyncTask, I have added the heavy code within the doInBackground() method however `readBuf.replace` and `readBuf.split` cannot be resolved. I thought to put the end changed in `onProgressUpdate()` as opposed to `onPostExecute()` as this would keep the UI elements updated automatically.

```
private class PostTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        readBuf = ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getReadBuf();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... readBuf) {
        while (readBuf.length > 4) {
            readBuf.replace("V", "");
            String[] parts = readBuf.split(",");
            String part1 = parts[0];
            String part2 = parts[1];
            speed1 = Float.parseFloat(part1);
            speed2 = Float.parseFloat(part2);
            finalspeed1 = (speed1 * 102) / div1;
            finalspeed2 = (speed2 * 602) / div1;
            publishProgress();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        speedometer.onSpeedChanged(speedometer.getCurrentSpeed() - speedcur1);
        speedometer.onSpeedChanged(speedometer.getCurrentSpeed() + finalspeed1);
        speedometer1.onSpeedChanged(speedometer.getCurrentSpeed() - speedcur2);
        speedometer1.onSpeedChanged(speedometer1.getCurrentSpeed() + finalspeed2);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: `handler.post` sends your runnable to the ui thread, so all your work is done on the ui thread. Plus you are looping (very quickly, since the `post` operation does basically nothing) and adding a new tasks each iteration to be completed on the ui thread.

Comment: also, probable typo on that line: `speedometer1.onSpeedChanged`

Comment: also, isn't `speedometer.getCurrentSpeed() - speedcur1` that going to be 0 anyway? and so will the next call to `speedometer.getCurrentSpeed()` ?

Comment: where do you update `readBuf` ? does it make sense to try to read it every time even if it does not change?

Comment: @njzk2 no `speedometer1` is intentional though I should probably name them `speedometer1` & `speedometer2` as there are two UI elements to update. Subtracting the `speedcur1` is supposed to remove the previous value after the current speed is obtained, resetting the value to 0, then the new value is given to the speedometer. `readBuf` is a String from a Messenger in my Application class, the contents of the string can vary as the message object comes from a Bluetooth InputStream.

Comment: no, but that part `speedometer1.onSpeedChanged(speedometer.getCurrentSpeed()` where  you use the value from `speedometer` on speedometer1

Comment: Ah you're right I didn't notice that, that could have done something horribly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You're starting a new thread which is actually just posting a new `Runnable` to the UI thread (`handler` is created on the UI thread), so it's not being done in the background.  Here are a few tips to help with this:

- If you are going to use a background thread to do the "work", then don't post a `Runnable` which is performing work to the `handler`, just post the result and update your UI accordingly.
- Don't call `findViewById()` in a loop or any time after creation, if possible.  Get a reference to the UI element and stash it off.  This method is expensive as it does a search through your view hierarchy for the matching ID.
- If you are going to use an `AsyncTask` just move the "work" part of your `Runnable` to the `doInBackground()` method and your UI updates into the `onPostExecute()` method.
- Whether using a custom background `Thread` or `AsyncTask`, be sure to shutdown/cancel the work when your `Activity` leaves the run state, otherwise you will encounter problems as these components are not lifecycle aware.
- It's not clear where `readBuf` is actually pulling data from, so this may also need some work.  If this is real-time data coming from some other source, then you may need to have the custom `Thread` loop with a small yield.  If using an `AsyncTask`, you'll have to create a new one each time as they are one-shot operations and not intended to be used as a long running background thread.

[This article](http://po.st/Cei3m2) on `AsyncTask` has more details about how it works and pitfalls.

Comment: `readBuf` is a String from a Messenger in my Application class, the contents of the string can vary as the message object comes from a Bluetooth InputStream, the device sending the data is sending a set of bytes approximately every 2 seconds.

Comment: then you should not looping, but reacting on the update of that value instead.

Comment: I believe Java doesn't have anything specifically for that situation, so it'll have to be self implemented?

Comment: Definitely should not be looping in this case.  The `Message` should contain the text to parse and that can quickly be offloaded to another thread (`HandlerThread` may be a good choice) or `AsyncTask` for parsing and processing as I've already outlined.

Comment: @LarrySchiefer are you saying I should do the parsing inside the application class's message handler then retrieve `finalspeed1` and `finalspeed2`

Comment: No, not necessarily.  All I'm saying is take your input data (text or otherwise) coming from `Messenger` and offload handling.  Parsing `String` data can be time consuming so offloading it to a `Thread` or `AsyncTask` is just fine.  But, repeatedly calling `findViewById()` is bad as well as just looping like this.  Make it event driven with any processing done in the background.